# Virtuemart & Paypal integration

Tags: paypal, virtuemart

I am using virtuemart and paypal.  The user will go through the whole checkout process fine, the page redirects to paypal for payment.  The user might have a different bill to address than ship to address.  If they select a different address in the paypal page it still has the billing address as the ship to address.  Any advice on how to clean up this problem?

Answer (score 0):

It shouldn't matter what address they select/enter in Paypal -- if they have selected the shipping address in Virtuemart then that address is what is stored in the Virtuemart Invoice/Purchase order.